# I want to POST from C # to DeepL API

Tags: c#, deepl

I want to POST from C # to DeepL API.
It just doesn't work.
Can anyone please tell me how?

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate");

httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("auth_key", "auth_key");
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("target_lang", "JA");

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    strSendJson = "{" +
                    "\"text\":\"" + strData.Trim() + "\"," +
                    "}";
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us what error or problem you are having so it's hard to tell

Comment: `auth_key` and `target_lang` fields are supposed to be sent as form fields. https://www.deepl.com/docs-api/

Comment: "It just doesn't work" is not a problem statement Stack Overflow can help with.

Comment: It's an obvious issue when you know the API, but can you please edit this post with the response from the server to make it complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DeepL Simpulator is a great place to start out: https://www.deepl.com/docs-api/simulator

When using POST, the `auth_key` is just another field in the form fields, its not a header.

> Because the content type is specified as `x-www-form-urlencoded` you are expected to send the data as a *url encoded* form, **not JSON**. Over the wire this should look something like:
>
> ```
> auth_key=[yourAuthKey]&text=Hello, world&target_lang=JA
> ```

The following shows how to send this POST request from C# using HttpClient:

```
string authKey = "~MyAuthKey~";

var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");       
Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "auth_key", authKey },
    { "text", strData.Trim() },
    { "target_lang", "JA" }
};
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate", 
    new System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent(data));
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
deeplResponseObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeepResponse>(json);

foreach(var tx in deeplResponseObj.translations) 
    Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" (from {1})", tx.text, tx.detected_source_language);
```

The following class definitions help with deserialization of the response:

```
public class DeepResponse
{
    List<DeepTranslation> translations { get;set; } = new List<DeepTranslation>();
}

public class DeepTranslation
{
    public string detected_source_language { get;set; }
    public string text { get;set; }
}
```